# Pascals triangle and binomial theory $(1+x)^n$ expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have a question that I can solve quite nicely with the binomial theorem; however, I am required to use pascals triangle for a lower level course:

> In the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ the first three terms are $1$, $-18$, and $144$. Determine the values of $x$ and $n$.

Answer: $x=-2$, $n=9$

But I don't know how to solve this using pascals triangle!

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Write the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ and see if you can make any associations.

Comment: Pascal's triangle only tells you $\binom n k$, mind you. These are the coefficients of $x^k$ in $(1+x)^n$, but they are not the entire term. Just bear that in mind.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks for the suggestion. How would I go about writing the expansion of (1+x)^n? I've only ever done expansion using pascals triangle when n is defined. Not sure what row to look at here! Thanks

Comment: Each row tells your the coefficients of an expansion. You'll need to use that as a guide.

Comment: Hint: The coefficients of the first three terms are $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{0}, ~\binom{n}{1}, ~\binom{n}{2}.$ First, solve for $~n,~$ and then solve for $~x.$

Comment: What's the difference between Pascal's triangle and the binomial theorem, except for the format?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got it by justifying pattern recognition (aka the binomial theorm).